# Android; BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file) returns null, file is known to exists

Tags: java, android, bitmapfactory

I am attempting to render a photo I have taken with the following class, which returns the used file:

```
public File takePhoto(){
    Intent pictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File destination= null;
    try {
        destination = createFile();
    } catch (IOException error) {
        Log.v(TAG, "IO error, reading exception");
        String errorMessage = error.getMessage();
        Log.v(TAG, errorMessage);
        String errorCauseMessage = error.getCause().getMessage();
       Log.v(TAG, errorCauseMessage);
    }
    if (destination != null){
        Log.v(TAG, "destination was written");
        pictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(destination));
        parentActivity.startActivityForResult(pictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        Log.v(TAG, "destination was: " + destination.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    else {
        Log.v(TAG, "destination was not written");
    }``
    return destination;
```

The result is then used in the following code:

```
Log.v(TAG, "adding picture");
            PhotoHandler photoHandler = new PhotoHandler(getPackageManager(), PolishCreateActivity.this);
            File imgFile = photoHandler.takePhoto();
            if (imgFile == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, ERROR_TOAST_TEXT, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG, "Picture added");

                Log.v(TAG, "storing directory");
                img = imgFile.getAbsolutePath();
                Log.v(TAG, "Directory stored");

                Log.v(TAG, "Displaying picture");
                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);
                if (imageViewExists == Boolean.TRUE) {
                    ImageView oldView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewID);
                    layout.removeView(oldView);
                }
                UIHelper uiHelper = new UIHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
                ImageView imageView = uiHelper.getImageViewFromPath(imgFile);
                imageView.setId(R.id.imageViewID);
                layout.addView(imageView);
                imageViewExists = Boolean.TRUE;
                Log.v(TAG, "picture displayed");
```

And passed to this method, as imgFile:

```
public ImageView getImageViewFromPath(File imgFile) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    Bitmap imgBM = null;
    if (imgFile.exists()) {
        Log.v(TAG, "image file exists");
        imgBM = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
        if (imgBM == null){
            Log.v(TAG, "Bitmap returned was null");
        }
    }
    imageView.setImageBitmap(imgBM);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    Log.v(TAG, "ImageView was created");
    return imageView;
}
```

The problem is that BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath) returns every time I run it, even though the file exists (I can tell because I'm getting the log messages in the "if (imgFile.exists())" body). I have searched for a solution for a long time, but I have not found a solution. I have tested that it is not causing an outOfMemory exception, which it is not. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you explay better your problem?

Comment: Are you sure: imgFile is not null. And getAbsolutePath() returns the correct path and isn't null or empty either?

Comment: Yes, imgFile is not null, and getAbsolutePath() is returning the correct path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`takePhoto` starts an activity for a result:

```
parentActivity.startActivityForResult(pictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
```

But your code carries on like this was done instantly, which it is not.
The file will of course be there, but it will always be 0 bytes large.

You will need to override `onActivityResult()` and handle the file contents from there.

Comment: I checked in the file manager; The files exists, are several hundred kilobytes in size, and can be viewed on the device. I can't see them on my computer, though.

Comment: I based this off [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html), which indicated that the picture would be saved without any need for onActivity result. Could you explain why this would be wrong and what I should do instead?

Comment: Yes, the file will be saved by the new Activity, but that will happen *afterwards*. The new image capturing Activity will not be visible until the current activity (from which you are calling `startActivityForResult` from) finishes. So, when you immediately try to display the contents of the file, there is nothing there - yet! You must wait for the new Activity to do its job, and this is accomplished by overriding `onActivityResult`.

Comment: Ah, I see! I've made another solution for the time being, but I'll remember this is image resolution becomes an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check for the sdk version you are using for sdk version 23 or above you have to take permission for reading and writing on device..check for the below code may be it will resolve your issue

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 if((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,                                  
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)       
                || (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))

        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions
                    (MainActivity.this, new String[]{
                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                    },MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_AND_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of imgFile.getAbsolutePath().

Probably this value is null or illegal.

Use debug mode or log this value to log cat.

Comment: I logged this values, and it points to a file in /storage/sdcard0/pictures/PolishApp*. I can view these files in the on-device file manager, but not the file manager on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved it by switching to getting the bitmap from the intent via onActivityResult.

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        photo = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);
        layout.addView(UIHelper.getImageViewFromPath(photo, getApplicationContext()));
    }
}
```

I still need to save the bitmap, though.